# ValueError: No tables found

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente script, me devuelve el error del título.

```
# Importar cotizaciones de varios ISIN definidos en un diccionario
import pandas as pd
import os
# Diccionario de ISIN 
dicc_isin = {"ES0112611001" :"azValor-Internacional", "ES0124037005":"Cobas-selection","LU0996182563":"Amundi MSCI",
             "ES0114673033":"Bestinfond","ES0180792006":"TrueValue", "FR0010149120":"CarminangSegurite",
             "LU0675297237":"G-Fund_Avenir"}  

# Directorio para la descarga de los df
os.chdir("E:/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Importacion_Cotizaciones/Ficheros_Funds")

def importar_cotizaciones(key, value):
    url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + value
    df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", parse_dates=True, 
                      decimal="," )[0]
    df.columns = (["Date", "Close"])
    df.columns = ['Close',key]
    df = df.set_index("Date")    
    df.to_excel (isin + ".xlsx")
    #df.to_csv(isin + ".csv")
    return df

for key, value in dicc_isin.items():
    df = importar_cotizaciones(key, value)
    print (df[:3])
```

Hago la prueba importando directamente de una lista con los Isin's y descarga correctamente.

## Importar cotizaciones de varios ISIN definidos en la lista "lista_ISIN"

import pandas as pd
import os

```
# Directorio para la descarga de los df
os.chdir("E:/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Importacion_Cotizaciones/Ficheros_Funds")

lista_ISIN = ["ES0112611001", "ES0124037005","LU0996182563","ES0114673033","ES0180792006", 
              "FR0010149120","LU0675297237"]
def importar_cotizaciones(isin):
    url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + isin
    df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", parse_dates=True, decimal="," )[0]
    df.columns = (["Date", "Close"])
    df = df.set_index("Date")    
    df.to_excel (isin + ".xlsx")
    #df.to_csv(isin + ".csv")
    return df
for isin in lista_ISIN:
    df = importar_cotizaciones(isin)
    print (df[:3])
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error¿. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Corregido el error siguiendo la sugerencia aportada por FJ.Sevilla, el script queda como sigue:

```
# Importar cotizaciones de varios ISIN definidos en un diccionario
import pandas as pd
import os
# Diccionario de ISIN 
dicc_isin = {"ES0112611001" :"azValor-Internacional", "ES0124037005":"Cobas-selection","LU0996182563":"Amundi MSCI",
             "ES0114673033":"Bestinfond","ES0180792006":"TrueValue", "FR0010149120":"CarminangSegurite",
             "LU0675297237":"G-Fund_Avenir"}  

# Directorio para la descarga de los df
os.chdir("E:/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Importacion_Cotizaciones/Ficheros_Funds")

def importar_cotizaciones(key, value):
    url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + key
    df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", parse_dates=True, 
                      decimal="," )[0]
    df.columns = (["Date", "Close"])
    df = df.rename(columns={'Close': value})
    df = df.set_index("Date")    
    df.to_excel (key + ".xlsx")
    #df.to_csv(isin + ".csv")
    return df

for key, value in dicc_isin.items():
    df = importar_cotizaciones(key, value)
    print (df[:3])
```

Comment: Hola, tienes los isins como claves, ¿no tendrías que usar la key para formar la url? `url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + key`

Comment: Efectivamente. Ese era el error. Habia dos errores más. ¿Procede que ponga cómo queda el script finalmente?. Gracias